# Trouble generating a model instance and applying it to a specific key in Ember Mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

While generating an instance of a staffMember within ember-cli-mirage I'm attempting to create a 'task' and assign it to the key 'tasksCreated' within the staffMember model. My current code is as follows;

It's creating a task, and creating a staffMember but the two have no relationships built between them.

app/models/staff-member.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    atWork: DS.attr('boolean'),
    avatar: DS.attr(),
    tasksCreated: DS.hasMany('task', {
        inverse: 'creator'
    }),
    tasksAssigned: DS.hasMany('task', {
        inverse: 'assignee'
    })
});
```

app/models/tasks.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    creator: DS.belongsTo('staff-member', { inverse: null }),
    assignee: DS.belongsTo('staff-member', { inverse: null }),
    creationDate: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    urgency: DS.attr()
 });
```

mirage/models/staff-member.js

```
import {Model, hasMany} from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Model.extend({
    tasksCreated: hasMany('task'),
    tasksAssigned: hasMany('task', { inverse: 'assignee'})
});
```

mirage/models/task.js

```
import {Model, belongsTo} from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Model.extend({
    creator: belongsTo('staff-member'),
    assignee: belongsTo('staff-member')
});
```

mirage/factories/staff-member.js

```
import { Factory, faker, trait } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
    name: faker.name.firstName,
    atWork: faker.random.boolean,
    avatar: faker.image.avatar,
    withTasks: trait({
        afterCreate(staffMember, server){
            server.createList('task',2,{tasksCreated: [staffMember]});
        }
    })
});
```

mirage/factories/task.js

```
import { Factory, faker } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default Factory.extend({
    creationDate: faker.date.recent,
    description: faker.lorem.sentence,
    urgency: faker.random.number({
        'min': 0,
        'max': 4
    })
});
```

mirage/scenarios/default.js

```
export default function(server ) {  

    server.createList('staff-member', 4, 'withTasks');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove most of the code that wasn't directly related to setting the relationships up. Before fiddling with the factories, try to get the relationships working in just the default scenario.

I've made a working twiddle here: https://ember-twiddle.com/5bcdcdee50faa0c0a679c3c4d35fe0ea?openFiles=mirage.scenarios.default.js%2C

Here's what the default scenario looks like:

```
export default function(server ) {  

  let member1 = server.create('staff-member');
  server.createList('task', 2, { creator: member1 });
  server.create('task', { assignee: member1 });


  let member2 = server.create('staff-member');
  server.create('task', { creator: member2 });
  server.createList('task', 3, { assignee: member2 });
}
```

As far as your factory `afterCreate` code goes, one error is in this line

```
server.createList('task',2,{tasksCreated: [staffMember]});
```

You're creating a `task`, but passing in `tasksCreated` as a property of that task. But tasks don't have a tasksCreated property, staffMembers do. Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
server.createList('task', 2, { creator: staffMember });
```